# Why Does JavaScript Automatically Allow My Function To Take An Extra Argument?

Tags: javascript, scope, prototypal-inheritance

I am not understanding JavaScript scoping and inheritance correctly. I clearly defined a function to take 1 argument (and I understand that this is optional due to how JavaScript handles arguments) but it looks like I need an extra argument to make the scoping work. Why is this?

```
ShapeRenderable.prototype = new Renderable();
function ShapeRenderable()
{
    this._line_join = 'round';
    this._line_cap = 'round';
    .
    .
} 

ShapeRenderable.prototype.setFillColor = function (fill_style)
{
    if (fill_style)
    {
        this._fill_style = fill_style;
        this.initialAlpha = fill_style._alpha;
    }
    else
    {
        this._fill_style = new RGBA(0,0,0,1.0);
    }
};



SelectionCube.prototype = new ShapeRenderable();

function SelectionCube()
{ 
    var self = this; // So we can access public methods and members from within
    // private ones.    

    self._visible = true;         
    self._scale = 1;
    self._stroke_style   = new RGBA(0,0,0,.1); // Lines solid black
    self._line_width = 7.0; // 1

    var platonicRenderable = new PlatonicRenderable(this);
    platonicRenderable.createCube(); 

    // surfaces mostly transparent white
    ShapeRenderable.prototype.setFillColor.call(this, new RGBA(255,255,255,1));
    // Why do I have to pass "this" to get the correct scope during 
    // execution of the above? If "this" isn't passed, it looks like JavaScript 
    // is scoping this for the parent, instead of for the child.
    // 
    // This is the correct behavior. My cube is now white.


}
```

If I just call:

```
ShapeRenderable.prototype.setFillColor.call(new RGBA(255,255,255,1));
```

Then my renderable is black (which is incorrect) and it looks like this._fill_style is never set correctly for my SelectionCube. Why is this? Is there some secret JavaScript optional (first) parameter which tells the function what scope to use during execution? I was having the above issue, and I read about passing this so that the [class reference will still point to the child](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/calling-parent-methods-in-javascript.html#fbid=m1WZcx9Oyeb) but I never understood why.

Here's what it looks like for the two cases: 
[image: Broken]
Broken - Not Updating "this" correctly

[image: Works]
Works - Updating "this" correctly

Comment: `call/apply` have a "thisArg" as the first parameter. Since methods in JavaScript are *not* bound to objects but are really just functions that "are known by various property names" (although see `bind`), it must be specified manually.

Comment: Why do you need that line at all? You should try `this.setFillColor(...)`, as you already setup the inheritance.

Comment: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call): the first argument of `call` is `this`, it's only the rest of arguments that are passed to the function as arguments.

Comment: Thanks. I don't need that line. My knowledge of JavaScript inheritance isn't as high as I'd like, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `.call` incorrectly. The correct syntax for `call` is

```
fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
```

See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

The first parameter is the "scope" or the `this` object within the function. Subsequent arguments are passed to your function's parameters.

However in this situation it's best to use @elclanrs suggestion in your comments.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using this.setFillColor(new RGBA(255,255,255,1)); as was suggested. I have no idea why I didn't use that before - likely I hadn't set everything up properly when I tried that.